# Vue3 - slot with v-model html rendered with render function

Tags: vuejs3, v-model, slots, vue-render-function

In vue3 I have this:

```
<template>
  <ChildComponent>
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="myValue"/>
    </div>
  </ChildComponent>
</template>
```

Here, in the child component the slot is rendered with input field, and it is binded to the myValue from the parent component.

How could I make it working with render function instead od declarative template like above?

In my app the slot inner html comes from the api rest service, but inserting it to the slot via v-html obviously does not work.

Comment: If you want to feed HTML to Vue at runtime - you will need the runtime template compiler or otherwise parse the HTML yourself and construct a corresponding rendering function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You can compile your inner html to a render function.

Here's a trick: we should provide a render context to the compiled render function with `myValue`. The problem that we cannot provide `myValue` as it is since the compiled function looks like that:

```
(function anonymous(Vue
) {
const _Vue = Vue
const { createElementVNode: _createElementVNode } = _Vue

const _hoisted_1 = ["onUpdate:modelValue"]

return function render(_ctx, _cache) {
  with (_ctx) {
    const { vModelText: _vModelText, createElementVNode: _createElementVNode, withDirectives: _withDirectives, openBlock: _openBlock, createElementBlock: _createElementBlock } = _Vue

    return (_openBlock(), _createElementBlock("div", null, [
      _withDirectives(_createElementVNode("input", {
        type: "text",
        "onUpdate:modelValue": $event => ((myValue) = $event)
      }, null, 8 /* PROPS */, _hoisted_1), [
        [_vModelText, myValue]
      ])
    ]))
  }
}
})
```

As you see the problem in

```
"onUpdate:modelValue": $event => ((myValue) = $event)
```

So basically the ref is overwritten, not changed (`myValue.value = $event`).
So we need to wrap our context into a reactive, that way when `myValue` in the context is changed, our linked `myValue` ref is changed too:

```
<script setup>

import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue';
import {compile, ref, reactive} from 'vue';

const myValue = ref('test');

const compiled = compile(`<div>
      <input type="text" v-model="myValue"/>
    </div>`);

const content = () => compiled(reactive({myValue}));

</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ myValue }}</div>
  <ChildComponent>
    <content/>
  </ChildComponent>
</template>
```

To support the compile you should change Vue's runtime:

vite.config.js:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it does not work. Changing the input value does not change the myValue value.

Comment: @plizzz you are welcome, that was an interesting task for me, thanks